# ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined：Gatsby with nivo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, nivo-react

I use @nivo/pie with `"gatsby": "^3.13.0"`.
But I got an error when I gatsby build.
`WebpackError: ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined`
Nivo's version is "@nivo/pie": "^0.79.1".
I have no idea to solve it. I would be appreciate if you could give me some advice.

And here is the React code using nivo's pie chart.

**PieChart.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { ResponsivePie } from '@nivo/pie'

const PieChart: React.FC = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ResponsivePie
            data={data}
            margin={{ top: 30, right: 80, bottom: 70, left: 80 }}
            borderColor={{
                from: 'color',
                modifiers: [
                    [
                        'darker',
                        0.2,
                    ],
                ],
            }}
            arcLabelsTextColor={{
                from: 'color',
                modifiers: [
                    [
                        'darker',
                        2,
                    ],
                ],
            }}
            fill={[
                {
                    match: {
                        id: 'ruby',
                    },
                    id: 'dots',
                },
            ]}
            legends={[
              {
                  anchor: 'bottom-right',
                  direction: 'column',
                  justify: false,
                  translateX: 0,
                  translateY: -1,
              },
          ]}
          />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default PieChart
```

===================================================================

I could fix it after I updated gatsby-node.js. But I got another error `WebpackError: Minified React error #130;`. And I could fix it by this final code. There's no build error.

**PieChart.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { ResponsivePie } from '@nivo/pie'

const PieChart: React.FC = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
        {typeof window !== 'undefined' && ResponsivePie &&
        <ResponsivePie
            data={data}
            ...  
        />}
    </>
  )
}

export default PieChart
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a null loader on Gatsby's SSR. In your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@nivo\/pie/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Normally this kind of issue (`gatsby develop` OK vs `gatsby build` KO) are related to webpack's bundling on the server (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering), especially when dealing with [third-party dependencies that interact with the `window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules) (such as `document`) like chart modules do. This happens because when you run `gatsby build` your code is interpreted by the Node server, where there's no window available yet. On the other hand, `gatsby develop` is interpreted by the browser, where there is.

With this approach, you are adding a dummy loader (`null`) to webpacks to load the dependency on the client-side, where the `window` is available.

Keep in mind that  `test: /@nivo\/pie/` is a regular expression (that's why is between slashes, `/`) that tests the `node_modules` folder so ensure that `/@nivo\/pie/` is a valid path.